# Getting video using UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to get a selected video from an iOS app using UIImagePickerController, and so far when the button is clicked it opens the PhotoLibrary perfectly fine and I select a video and it says `compressing video`, so it's acting like its selecting it but after that nothing really happens. And I can't really seem to figure out why.

```
var picker = UIImagePickerController()
var imag = UIImagePickerController()

...

@IBAction func selectMediaAction(sender: UIButton) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary){
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
        self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!) {
    let media = editingInfo[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]
    let imageURL = media?.filePathURL as NSURL?
    mediaPath = imageURL
    mediaName.text = imageURL!.lastPathComponent
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    toggleSubmit()
}

@IBAction func createMediaAction(sender: UIButton) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera){
        imag.delegate = self
        imag.allowsEditing = false
        imag.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        imag.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
        self.presentViewController(imag, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else{
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "There is no camera available on this device", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? It looks to me like it should be working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have will only check for the image types. If you want to get the selected video information, you need to look for the key  `UIImagePickerControllerMediaType` and you need to use the delegate method `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` not the `didFinishPickingImage`

```
  NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
```